# set opacity to parent div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have developed android phonegap application using javascript.
I am having one parent div and one child div inside.When i click the the button i will open the child div as like popup.But problem is i need to set opacity for my parent div not the child div.How to do this using javascript or css.

HTML code:

```
<div id="parent">
 <input type="button" value="open"/>
 <div id="child">
 </div>
  </div>
```

Please kindly help me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use transparent (.png) image in background with same color as overlay color you need, that's best...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend you this:

css:

```
#parent.faded {
  opacity: 0.5;
  // more css
}
```

javascript:

```
obj.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('parent').className = 'faded';
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But it applied to whole parent div including child div.But i no need to apply opacity for child div.

Comment: so put child div outside of parent div. simple like that

Comment: Is there any other options to get opacity for only parent div not the child div.

Comment: Then how to remove the opacity of the parent div in another button click.